# swift: remove variable whitespace for loading array

Tags: arrays, swift, whitespace

I have text files containing data with variable amounts of white space between the values. To extract the data I've loaded it into a string. I've then made an array of the lines using componentsSeparatedByString("\n"). So each element of this array contains a string with an atoms symbol, x , and z position and, for some molecules, a radius and residue symbol.
Each of these sample lines would be an element:

C      11.01600      2.60800     18.68400 1.95 T
C       9.14000      1.29600     19.60800 1.95 T
P       4.62800     -2.84000     19.21200 2.08 A

But now I need to make arrays for each element in the big array. Let's call them "subArrays". The varying amount of whitespace makes it difficult to apply any standard code I know of. I've tried filling the subArray using componentsSeparatedByString(" ") which gets my values as elements but burdened with whitespace elements inbetween. I've tried iterating over the members of the subArray to remove the whitespace elements but this doesn't seem to work. Plus I'd rather avoid this if possible as it would considerably increase the load time for the models and make interaction such as user resizing unfeasible. Some of these models are a couple thousand lines long.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try `let comps = inStr.componentsSeparatedByString("\n").map{ $0.componentsSeparatedByString(" ").filter{ !$0.isEmpty } }`

Comment: Thanks Leo. Pradeep's answer below easily fit right in to my existing code and worked well. But I intend to experiment with what you've posted when time avials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let s1 = oneLine.componentsSeparatedByString(" ").filter{ $0 != ""}
print(s1)
```

Where oneLine is one line of the element. First array will give you different elements including the "" and the filter will remove all "" from the array and give you just the 6 data values of your line.

E.g.

```
var oneLine = "C   11.01600        2.60800 18.68400 1.95 T"
let s1 = str.componentsSeparatedByString(" ").filter{ $0 != ""}
```

s1 will be "["C", "11.01600", "2.60800", "18.68400", "1.95", "T"]\n"

Comment: Thanks so much, Pradeep... works perfectly. I I know that's a closure and the $0 is a shorthand reference, I guess to the "components" But what exactly would you replace the $0 with if you were being verbose?. [BTW, ironically I see Stackoverflow has deleted the extra whitespace from my example! I see you figured that out. Thanks again.]

Comment: You can use a named variable in the filter { }. E.g `filter { (dataValue:String) in dataValue != ""` }